# Using tweenlite to tween 3d coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, coordinates, papervision3d, gsap

im trying to tween a sprite to new 3D coordinates (x,y,z) using AS3 and i would like to use TweenLite to do it but i don't know how?

Im not a very experienced programmer, i only started to tackle the 3d possibilities of flash 10 and Tweenlite has been really helpful so far for my animations.

I've been trying to use the QuaternionsPlugin like this:

```
TweenLite.to(myMc, 2, {quaternions:{orientation:new Quaternion(x, y, z, w)}});
```

There's the x,y,z properties but i couldn't figure out what w stand for.
I tried an example with the Sprite class below but when i compile it, it says : 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Quaternion.

```
package com{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;  
import com.greensock.TweenLite; 
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin; 
import com.greensock.plugins.QuaternionsPlugin;  

TweenPlugin.activate([QuaternionsPlugin]); //activation is permanent in the SWF, so this line only needs to be run once.

public class Carousel extends Sprite {
     public function Carousel():void {      

    }

    public function scrollUp():void{
        TweenLite.to(Mc1, 2, {quaternions:{orientation:new Quaternion(246, 244, 0, 400)}});
        TweenLite.to(Mc2, 2, {quaternions:{orientation:new Quaternion(242, 210, 70, 353)}});
    }

    public function scrollDown():void{
        TweenLite.to(Mc1, 2, {quaternions:{orientation:new Quaternion(242, 290, 60, 360)}});
        TweenLite.to(Mc2, 2, {quaternions:{orientation:new Quaternion(246, 244, 0, 400)}});
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any hint/help, really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the *Quanternion* object is from [PaperVision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/)'s math class.  "w" is for the angle of rotation and a quaternion guarantees the the most efficient path for the rotation.

[Vector3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html) objects have w properties.  Matrix3D's *[interpolate()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html#interpolate%28%29)* method uses quaternions, so you could tween using Matrix3D's [intropolate()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html#interpolate%28%29) or [transformVector()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html#transformVector%28%29) methods, or you could simply tween the x, y, and z properties of your display object - assuming you don't require the absolute most efficient rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have a better understanding and a few more things to dig in. It's been helpful.